# How to fetch data of specific class through php DOM parser in loop?

Tags: php, dom

I am new to PHP DOM parser. I can retrieve simple data like any div or all links etc, but in my work I need to extract data of class with specific name. In my case I need to extract data of all  from this link, http://www.dawn.com/archive/2014-12-03/

Can any one please tell me how to extract data of such divs when id is not given and I need extraction through class name. I will be very grateful for this favor.

Here is all my code which is working:

```
<?php
    include("simple_html_dom.php");
    $html=file_get_html("http://www.dawn.com/archive/2014-12-03/");

    //to show all links/refrences
    foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
    ?>
```

but I want to show data of classes, I am trying this:

```
foreach($html->find("div#story__excerpt") as $element)
echo $element;
```

but this one is not giving output.

Comment: can you show some code that you currently use to extra the simple data? perhaps that can be modified/extended to solve this bigger problem.

Comment: yeah I can. here it is,

Comment: <?php
 include("simple_html_dom.php");
 $html=file_get_html("http://www.dawn.com/archive/2014-12-03/");
   //to show all links
 foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
?>

Comment: I have updated question.

Comment: Grammar, spelling, formatting

Answer (score 0):

looking at the HTML source of the URL you're trying to pull from, i see that the class name isn't exactly what you think it is. here's what it looks like in the source:

```
<div class='story__excerpt      '>
```

note the spaces in the class. maybe try a find with a wildcard or a regex-based find, if it's supported.

Answer (score 0):

To get elements by class use `.` the `#` should be used to reference elements by id.

```
foreach($html->find("div.story__excerpt") as $element) {
    echo $element;
}
```

Here is the reference for all [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)